# Are there any field extensions of the complex numbers with the following properties?

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, complex-analysis

Is there a field $P \supsetneq \Bbb{C}$ with the following properties:

1. $P$ is algebraically closed.
2. There exists a function $f : P \to \{x \in \Bbb{R}, x \ge 0\}$ such that

   2.a. $f(z) = |z|$ for all $z \in \Bbb{C}$.

   2.b. $f(xy) = f(x)f(y)$ for all $x, y, \in P$.

   2.c. $f(x) + f(y) \ge f(x + y)$ for all $x, y, \in P$.
3. For every set $S \subsetneq P$ with $S \ne \emptyset$, there exists some $b \in P$ such that every neighborhood of $b$ contains a point in $S$ and a point not in $S$. A *neighborhood* of $b$ is defined as any set $\{x \in P: f(x - b) \le r\}$ where $r$ is a positive real number.

Comment: Or, in more standard terminology, is there an absolute value on a nontrivial algebraically closed extension $P$ of $\mathbb{C}$ extending the usual absolute value such that $P$ is connected in the induced topology?

Comment: This formulation makes it clear that property 3 follows from property 2: $P$ is a topological vector space and so is automatically connected.

Answer (score 2):

It is impossible to satisfy (2) alone.  Indeed, taking such a field $P$ with absolute value function $f$, we can take the completion of $P$ with respect to $f$ and thus assume without loss of generality that $P$ is complete.  But then the [Gelfand-Mazur theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfand%E2%80%93Mazur_theorem) says that $P$ cannot be a proper extension of $\mathbb{C}$.

(Note that (2) also immediately implies property (3), since property (3) just says that $P$ is connected and any normed vector space over $\mathbb{C}$ is connected.)

Comment: Could you help me with this please https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3292324/show-the-quotient-space-of-a-finite-collection-of-disjoint-2-simplices-obtained? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The non-existence of a field $P$ with the required properties is proven in E. Weiss, Algebraic Number Theory, McGraw Hill, 1963.

Comment: Page? Theorem/Proposition?

Comment: Sorry, I have no access to the book of Weiss. The mentioned result is cited in the book O. Endler, Valuation Theory on page 15 as Lemma 1-8-2.